# Swift: How to transform a normal function to return a closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class called CustomPhotoAlbum that has the following function:

```
    func save(image: UIImage) {

        self.checkAuthorizationWithHandler { (success) in
            if success, self.assetCollection != nil {
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                    let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                    if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection) {
                        let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
                        albumChangeRequest.addAssets(enumeration)
                    }

                }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                    if success {
                        print("Successfully saved image to Camera Roll.")

                    }
                    else {
                        print("Error writing to image library: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

Which returns nothing. 
I then called the function like this

```
CustomPhotoAlbum.shared.save(image: finalImage)
```

My question is, how can i make it return the completionHandler so that i can do something like present an alert from my view controller?

Maybe something like this for me to call

```
CustomPhotoAlbum.shared.save(image: finalImage) { success in
// do something if successfully saved
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `completion: (Bool) -> Void` parameter and call it whenever appropriate:

```
func save(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    self.checkAuthorizationWithHandler { (success) in
        if success, self.assetCollection != nil {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection) {
                    let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
                    albumChangeRequest.addAssets(enumeration)
                }

            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                if success {
                    print("Successfully saved image to Camera Roll.")

                }
                else {
                    print("Error writing to image library: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                completion(success) // here!
            })

        } else {

            completion(false) // and here!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add closure as param in save function, like this:

```
func save(image: UIImage, @escaping completion: ()->Void) { 

    self.checkAuthorizationWithHandler { (success) in
        if success, self.assetCollection != nil {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection) {
                    let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
                    albumChangeRequest.addAssets(enumeration)
                }

            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                if success {
                    print("Successfully saved image to Camera Roll.")

                }
                else {
                    print("Error writing to image library: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
```